# H-bridge output voltage ripple

Tags: power-electronics, inverter

[image]I have built this H-bridge. I have a problem with the output ripple. I have used an RC snubber circuit (10,30,50 and 60nf with 5 ohm,) but still have the same problem. I checked the gate signal. It is perfect but when I apply the DC link small ripple appears. The picture below is the output voltage on no load. I used both IGBT and SIC MOSFET but with no luck. I am using DSP launchpad to control the gate signal. I also checked all the gate signal they all get distorted when I apply the input DC voltage

[image]

Comment: This cannot be explained without a schematic and details of how you monitored the signal using the oscilloscope. You say you checked the gate signal but, there will be four gate signals so, did you check them all? Also, what does this mean: **when I apply the DC link**? Please post a schematic.

Comment: How can I post the schematic picture

Comment: Post a schematic means post an image of your circuit diagram @deia

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: The ringing is because of the current sensing transducer LA25-NP, which is inductive in nature. Try increasing the resistor of the snubber circuit to the range of 200 ohms or so. The damping increases and the ringing should decrease

Comment: I don't see any decoupling or bulk capacitance on the bridge.

Comment: @deia you can do a screenshot capture and crop it and add it as an image it's a little bit more readable